Does Electron–positron annihilation produce gravitational wave?
Does Electron–positron annihilation produce gravitational waves?
Or does any annihilation or pair production give gravitational waves? How energy will be distributed between EM waves and gravitational waves?

@JohnRennie and other close voters: this question doesn't appear to ask about annihilation into gravitons. I interpret it like whether the act of annihilation produces gravitational waves similarly to, say, the merger of black holes.

@Ruslan The two are the same thing. Producing gravitons is producing gravitational waves, just like photons and electromagnetic radiation.

@VincentThacker Annihilation and producing waves is not the same. Atoms also produce EM waves when relaxing from excited states, yet they are not annihilating in this process.

@Ruslan I don't understand. This question is asking about electron-positron annihilation. The duplicate is also asking about electron-positron annihilation. Neither question is asking about wave production without annihilation. The duplicate identification is correct.

This question is asking about wave production during annihilation, yielding the typical products of annihilation (photons) PLUS gravitational waves. The other question asks about gravitons being the products of the annihilation, rather than a "byproduct".

@Ruslan If something is produced, it is produced. Whether it is deemed as a "product" or "byproduct" is irrelevant. I think the distinction is small enough.

The currently available physical theories are not able to give you a definite answer to this.

The theory of general relativity is our best-known theory, describing physics as large scales. In principle, by definition, the theory also talks about small scales (atomic scales). However, the validity of this scale is questionable, as it is in conflict with the ideas of quantum mechanics.

Quantum mechanics is the best-known formalism to describe the behaviour of the subatomic realm. But it does not include (General relativistic)-gravity


We currently don't have a theory that combines general relativity with quantum mechanics. Nonetheless, your question can be answered with different approximations to such a theory.

Classical particles in curved spacetime. 
If we treat our classical particles as mere test particles (not perturbing the geometry), the particles would just move according to the geodesics equations. Note that the set of initial conditions such that two geodesics intersect at some point is a null set. Thus, particle absorption doesn't typically happen.

Classical particles treated as black holes. 
If you treated particles as masses localized to a single point, they would form a black hole, according to Einstein's theory of gravity. There are ways to model classical as tiny black holes. In this case, we could interpret the absorption of a particle as a black hole merger; this would create gravitational waves, not because of the emission itself but because of the spiral movements of the "particles" before the collision. However, these waves are so small that they are many orders of magnitude away from anything that could be observed.

Non-relativistic quantum mechanics with Newtonian gravity. 
We can incorporate Newtonian gravity into non-relativistic quantum mechanics by using the Schrödinger equation
\begin{align}
i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} = - \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \Delta_i \Psi + V \Psi\,,
\end{align}
where the potential is given by
\begin{align}
V(\vec x_1, \dots, \vec x_n) = 
\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{|\vec x_i- \vec x_j|}
-\sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n}\frac{G m^2}{|\vec x_i- \vec x_j|}\,.
\end{align}
You can further add wave functions for different particle numbers and allow for particle creation and annihilation. None of this would create gravitational waves since only Newtonian gravity is incorporated. Likewise, the potential above would not lead to electromagnetic waves since only the electrostatic Coulomb potential is incorporated.

Quantum field theory on curved spacetime. 
As for classical Newtonian particles on curved background spacetime, there are no back reactions to spacetime, so no gravitational waves.

Non-renormalizable Quantum gravity: If we write the metric $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$ as a perturbation of the Minkowski metric, we can try to "quantize" the perturbation $h_{\mu\nu}$ in a particle physics style. This theory will not be renormalizable, but let's ignore this issue. If you look at the Feynman rules of gravity, you see that there are no typically no vertices such that a matter particle is emitted or absorbed while a graviton is emitted. (Note that Feynman diagrams do not really correspond to emission and absorption processes; they are just a visualization of perturbative calculations and not processes in spacetime. For a detailed discussion, see, e.g., Passon). So in some sense, there are gravity waves emitted.


In general, I guess it is not the emission or absorption that would potentially cause gravitational waves but the movement of approaching particles.
I hope this gives a little (incomplete) overview of possible answers to the question.
